# Compile a kernel module using qmake project

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake

I have the following project structure:

```
/
    general.pro
    a/
        a.pro
        some files
    b/
        b.pro
        some files
    c/
        Makefile
        some files
```

`general.pro` is a `TEMPLATE=subdirs` style qmake-project. The two other project files are normal/common qmake project files (folder a and b). The third folder (folder c) contains a kernel module with the following `Makefile`: http://pastebin.com/Bv39D6KK

I'm wondering if that `Makefile` can be translated somehow to a qmake project file.
If not, is there a way to the the `general.pro` project file that there is a "c" folder containing a Makefile which should be ran too?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt, you can include Makefile in a .pro file.

Here is my thoughts about what you can do:

1. If `c` is your project, you could simply create one more .pro file for it.
2. If it is not, and you don't need to edit it, you could build it without including into subdirs (if it's a library, you are using in `a` or `b`, you still can build it, and then create a .pri file and add includes and libs etc).
3. If you need it for a build machine or for deploying, you could use build script.
4. You could use `cmake`.

**Update**:

It turns out, [there is a solution.](http://www.qtforum.org/article/14616/mixing-qmake-makefiles-and-standard-mafefiles.html)

Though, I could not make it work myself, I hope it helps. What you need is to add following lines to a top-level pro file:

```
mytarget.commands = make -C c
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += mytarget
PRE_TARGETDEPS += mytarget
```

Where `c` is a name of sub-directory, containing `Makefile`.

Comment: ```c``` is the kernel module, while ```a``` and ```b``` are applications with their own, proper, project files (.pro). ```general.pro``` builds ```a``` and ```b``` when ```qmake && make``` is ran, and I'd like to make it run also the Makefile in ```c```, or, if this is impossible, translate somehow the Makefile I pastebin-ed to a .pro file.

Comment: Well, after some research, I found possible solution of adding `Makefile` to .pro.

Comment: I also found that, but it won't work placing it in my ```general.pro``` file as it's a ```TEMPLATE=subdirs``` instead of an ```app``` template, which menas it just won't parse those commands. (Please correct me if I'm wrong here)

Comment: Well, you could add a new dummy subproject, and add these lines to it, or you could even add it to one of existing pro files with command `make -C ../c` (or something like this).

Comment: You mean I can write plain ```Makefile``` instructions inside a ```.pro``` file? Or what do you mean by "dummy subproject" ?

Comment: Inside of directory `c` you create file `c.pro`, which contains `mytarget` and add it to `general.pro` as a subdir. The only problem is, if `c.pro` won't contain anything, except those three lines, the compiler will complain about missing `main`, so you could create a mini application, which does nothing. This I call `a dummy subproject`